# Time complexity of adding a new item to the back of a array-based list

Tags: data-structures, arraylist, big-o, time-complexity

If somebody asked me:" What is the running time complexity of adding a new item to the back of an array-based list?" How do I need to answer it? It can be treated as being `O(1)` since it is random access. But what if the `resize()` method is called before inserting(`resize()`method is used to double the size of array when it is full)? In this case will be linear time. Therefore, which one is correct? `O(1)` or `O(n)`?

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, since I have a lot of problems refer to big-o. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis), it is O(1), though it depends on the strategy for increasing the size of the list.

If we just increase the size of the array by one when it is full, it is O(n), since when we perform many inserts, we have to copy the entire list for each insert.

If we double the size of the array each time it is full, we will be copying relatively rarely. Amortized, or averaged, this becomes O(1).

This data structure is often called a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).